# PerformSegueWithIdentifier not making the transition

Tags: xcode, swift, macos, cocoa, viewcontroller

So I am trying to perform a segue as soon as the window loads without having to click a button or have any action performed. The segue's are linked from a view controller, but not linked from the window controller because I can only get one segue to link from the Windowcontroller at a time.  I tried this code in both "windowWillLoad" and "windowDidLoad" directly, and with it's own function. It isn't making the transition. Does it always have to be activated with a button? Can I not use segue's that aren't linked directly to the WindowController itself? I basically want to be able to choose between two different view controllers on the launch of the cocoa mac app.

```
import Cocoa

class WindowOne: NSWindowController {
var i = 0

override func windowWillLoad() {


}
override func prepareForSegue(segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if i == 0  {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("segone", sender: self)

    } else {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("segtwo", sender: self)
    }
}

override func windowDidLoad() {
    super.windowDidLoad()


}
```

}

Comment: A segue doesn't need a button but it has to be performed by an instance of the class where it's defined.

Comment: Philip, do you mean the view controller that the segue is coming from? Can you please elaborate? I was hoping to skip loading the view controller where the segues are coming from, and jump straight to the segues and where they are going. I am guessing that is probably impossible then?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the segue cannot be performed until the window has actually appeared - and at the point that `windowDidLoad` gets called it hasn't.

In iOS land we would handle this by calling `performSegueWithIdentifier` in the `viewDidAppear` method.

Here there are two options, as per this answer: [viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear on NSWindowController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24086398/viewwillappear-or-viewdidappear-on-nswindowcontroller)

Either override the `showWindow` method:

```
import AppKit

class WindowOne: NSWindowController {

    var i = 1

    override func showWindow(_ sender: Any?) {

        super.showWindow(sender)

        if i == 0  {
            performSegueWithIdentifier("segone", sender: self)
        } else {
            performSegueWithIdentifier("segtwo", sender: self)
        }
    }
}
```

Or for more fine-grained behaviour one might catch `NSWindowDelegate` calls. For example if you wanted the segue to occur whenever the window comes to the foreground you might implement `windowDidBecomeKey`:

```
import AppKit

class WindowOne: NSWindowController, NSWindowDelegate {

    var i = 1

    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()
        self.window?.delegate = self
    }

    func windowDidBecomeKey(_ notification: Notification) {
        if i == 0  {
            performSegueWithIdentifier("segone", sender: self)
        } else {
            performSegueWithIdentifier("segtwo", sender: self)
        }

    }
}
```